# i cant trigger azure ml pipeline from synapse because of this error User starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a working pipeline in Azure ML and I successfully ran it in Azure ML workspace (notebook) and I published the pipeline so I can use it in synapse analytics, but when I try to trigger the pipeline in synapse I get this error:

> Failed to submit job due to Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (User starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance). User starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance.

Here is my component code. I tried with both compute cluster and computer instance and I get the same issue.

```
import os  
import argparse  
from azureml.core import Dataset
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
import logging
# import mlflow
def main():
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--data",type=str,help="data lake gen2 path for input data")
    parser.add_argument("--path",type=str,help="path for output")
    parser.add_argument("--outputdata",type=str,help="data lake gen2 path for output data")
    args=parser.parse_args()
    print("test testtest testtest test")
    # mlflow.start_run()
    #my func
    data_path="csv web path"
    # mlflow.log_metric("data_path", args.data)
    dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(data_path, separator=',',set_column_types=None)
    print(dataset.to_pandas_dataframe().head())
    df = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
    token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    account_url = f"ACCOUNTURl LINK"
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=token_credential)
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client("dataasset2")
    directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("test")
    file_name = args.path
    file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(file_name)
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')
    file_client.upload_data(csv_data, overwrite=True)
    # mlflow.end_run()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I did try to create a compute cluster and I'm getting this error when I run the pipeline in Azure ML notebook.

```
Execution failed. User process 'python' exited with status code 1. Please check log file 'user_logs/std_log.txt' for error details. Error:     dataflow = _transform_and_validate(
  File "/azureml-envs/sklearn-1.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/data/dataset_factory.py", line 1225, in _transform_and_validate
    _validate_has_data(dataflow, 'Failed to validate the data.')
  File "/azureml-envs/sklearn-1.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/data/dataset_error_handling.py", line 69, in _validate_has_data
    raise DatasetValidationError(error_message + '\n' + e.compliant_message, exception=e)
azureml.data.dataset_error_handling.DatasetValidationError: DatasetValidationError:
    Message: Failed to validate the data.
ScriptExecutionException was caused by StreamAccessException.
  Unable to authenticate data access to '[REDACTED]'.
    AuthenticationException was caused by AzureIdentityAccessTokenResolutionException.
      Compute has no identity provisioned.
| session_id=771c548f-2dbd-4bce-a8b9-eec29c26257b
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Failed to validate the data.\nScriptExecutionException was caused by StreamAccessException.\n  Unable to authenticate data access to '[REDACTED]'.\n    AuthenticationException was caused by AzureIdentityAccessTokenResolutionException.\n      Compute has no identity provisioned.\n| session_id=771c548f-2dbd-4bce-a8b9-eec29c26257b"
    }
}
```

Nothing is working. How to make the compute cluster to authenticate with azure data lake gen2 ? And how can I try to start the compute instance or cluster from synapse? I'm even trying from the same account that I'm the owner of both workspace (ML and synapse).

Comment: what is `csv web path`. Is it starting with `http[s] or abfs[s] or wasb[s]`

Comment: it's starting with https

Comment: You have managed identity created in your cluster or compute instance right?

Comment: If yes you need to give permission to it for accessing the adls gen 2

Comment: yes i have system managed identity when i enabled it i got a principal id but that principal id i cant see it in the storage worksapce to give it access

Comment: Check this answer i have given.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903906/how-to-give-an-azure-ml-compute-cluster-access-to-data-lake-gen2-storage

Comment: I am posting it as an answer, so that it will help for community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this documentation

[azureml.data.dataset_factory.TabularDatasetFactory class - Azure Machine Learning Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-dataset-factory-tabulardatasetfactory-from-delimited-files)

```
Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files
```

accepts paths of url string (http[s]|abfs[s]|wasb[s]), [DataPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.datapath.datapath?view=azure-ml-py) object, or tuple of [Datastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore(class)?view=azure-ml-py) and relative path

If you use URL string then by default it uses managed identity or login identity for authorization.

So, need to give either `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or `Storage Blob Data Reader` based on your requirement.

To use Managed identity for credential you can use below code in your script.

```py
client_id = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID') 
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id=client_id)
```

This takes the system assigned managed identity client id and creates credential.

Make sure you assign any one of the above roles in storage account IAM.

Refer below stack solution for more information.

[how to give an azure ML compute cluster access to data lake gen2 storage? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903906/how-to-give-an-azure-ml-compute-cluster-access-to-data-lake-gen2-storage)

Comment: i did assign user identity to the compute cluster and i assigned to it blob storage contributor but i get this error
Attempted credentials:
 EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.
 ManagedIdentityCredential: Unexpected content type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
Content: InternalError - :{
Info: Request failure status code: 404

}

Comment: It is is taking `EnvironmentCredential ` by default. Try using `ManagedIdentity` instead of using `DefaultAzureCredential`

`client_id = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID')
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id=client_id)`

Comment: print client_id and see if your see the the assigned user identity client id. If not you not assigned the user identity.

Comment: Refer this link for how the `DefaultAzureCredential ` works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python

Comment: please post this as an answer

Comment: @theprogrammer Updated the solution. Kindly check it