# how to give an azure ML compute cluster access to data lake gen2 storage?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-managed-identity, azure-data-lake-gen2

when i try to run an azure ML pipeline that has inside it a connection to datalake storage using compute cluster (python sdk v2), i get an error that the compute cluster doesnt have access to the storage but when i run the pipeline using compute instance that is assigned to me i dont have any problem but im trying to do automation using synapse pipeline so i need to use a compute cluster not compute instance.

i tried to give the azure ml workspace owner access to data lake gen2 storage but that didnt fix the problem,i tried to use managed identity on the cluster and i got a principal id but when i try to add that given principal id to datalake storage in IAM access i cant enter a principal id in it i only can write a user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps below to grant access to your cluster using managed identity.

1. Copy the principal ID you obtained when creating the compute cluster.

[image]

2. Go to **Enterprise applications** in `Microsoft Entra ID`.

[image]

3. Search for the managed identity using the principal ID you copied earlier.

[image]

4. You will see the name and details of the managed identity. Copy its name and go to the ADLS Gen 2 account to grant access.

Give `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or `Storage Blob Data Reader` based on your requirement.

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to use user managed identities on compute clusters?

Comment: You can use. While enabling managed identies you will get option for user managed identies

Comment: I have an user managed identity that works with compute instances, but when assigned to a compute cluster. It doesn't have all rbac roles. For example I lose ADLS Gen2 storage access.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940295/aml-compute-instance-and-compute-cluster-roles-rbac

Comment: You need to contact your administrator who can give access to your application.

Comment: I am the "administrator"... I made the terraform to create all the ressources, create managed identities and assign roles to them.